# How do I add two dictionary list value and save within the same dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I add two lists from the same dictionary and assign then into the same dictionary with a different key?

I'm learning old Django1.8 and working with python3.6.

```
def tempcode(request):
    context = {
        "list_1":list(range(1,6)),
        "list_2":['A','B','C','D','E'],
        "list_3":[{{ tempcode.list_1 }},{{ tempcode.list_2}}],
    }
```

I can simply just define lists above context but I was wondering if there's a way to do this.

**EDIT**
I tried Gorav's suggestion:

```
def tempcode(request):
    context = {
        "list_1":list(range(1,6)),
        "list_2":['A','B','C','D','E'],
        "list_3":[],
    }
context[list_3] = context['list_1'] + context['list_2']
```

but it merged two components:

```
{{ list_3 }} == [1,2,3,4,5,'A','B','C','D','E']
```

What I was trying to do was to make `list_3`:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],['A','B','C','D','E']]
```

Initially, I was trying to make it happen within `context` but I learned that it's impossible.

Comment: `context = {} context["list_1"]=list(range(1,6)) ...` add them one by one

Comment: Im not sure what you want to achieve. But, try following code:

context['list_3'] = context['list_1'] + context['list_2']

Comment: So I want to pre define context so the codes work gradually, not simultaneously ?

Comment: Turend out adding merges two lists. I want components to be lists themselves.

Comment: use `context['list_3'].append(context['list_1'])`

Comment: Array1 + Array2 in Python will concatenate Array2 onto the Array1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to share the same list, ie. if you change `list1` you want the change to be reflected in `list3`, do:

```
context[list_3] = [context['list_1'], context['list_2']]
```

If you want them to be independent, do instead:

```
context[list_3] = [context['list_1'].copy(), context['list_2'].copy()]
```